# how can I delete an element from a type-list?

Tags: c++, templates, scheme, template-meta-programming

I have implemented scheme-like list of ints using templates in c++ :

```
class Empty {};

template <int H, class T = Empty>
struct list {
  static const int head = H;
  typedef T tail;

};
```

I'm trying to implement sorting function, so I decided I will use function : remove and find_min.
Algorithm is : find minimum in the list, create a list with this minimum as head , and remove it from the tail (the rest of the list). What's important I want it to be implemented recursively, without any loops. My min_function :

```
template <class T,int N>
struct min_elem{};


template<int H, class T,int N>
struct min_elem<list<H,T>,N >{


static const int value = (N>H ? min_elem<T,H>::value : min_elem<T,N>::value  );

};


template<int N>
struct min_elem<Empty,N>{
    static const int value=N;
};

template <class T>
struct min{};

template <int I, class T>
struct min<list<I,T> > {

    static const int value = min_elem<list<I,T>, I>::value;
};
```

but I have no idea how to implement delete function. I want it to be similar to min function. Can anyone help? The layout of funtion should be :

```
template<class T, int K>
struct re{};

template<int I, class T, int K>
struct re <list<I,T>,K>{

     typedef list<  ?? don't know what should I exactly do here> value;

};

template<int I>
struct re <Empty,I>{

     ??

};
```

Comment: You might be interested in boost::mpl: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
template<class T, int K> struct re;

template<int H, class T>
struct re <list<H, T>, H> { // the head and the subject are same value.
     typedef T type;
};

template<int H, class T, int K>
struct re <list<H, T>, K>{
     typedef list<H, typename re<T, K>::type> type;
};

template<int K>
struct re <Empty, K>{
     typedef Empty type;
};
```